# Center text in minibuffer/echo area?

Tags: window, frames, minibuffer, echo-area

**Q:** is there a way to center the minibuffer/echo area horizontally?

I use Emacs in a single, very wide frame split into three windows
side by side.  I'm usually working in the *center* window, with
the other windows showing notes, a REPL, etc.:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |           |
|   notes   | EYES HERE |   notes   |
|           |           |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| echo                              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

When I use the minibuffer or get a message in the echo area, the
text is flush with the left side of the frame.  On super wide
frames like the one I'm using, this placement is really
inconvenient.

*Is there a way to make minibuffer/echo area text show up in the
center of the frame (i.e., in the middle along the x-axis)?*

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |           |
|   notes   | EYES HERE |   notes   |
|           |           |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|            echo here?             |
+-----------------------------------+
```

In a perfect world, the minibuffer/echo area would start flush
with the left margin of the active window, but I'd be
glad if I could just get the text moved to the middle of the frame.

Comment: I haven't tried it but look at this post http://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/center-buffer-text-in-emacs.html

Comment: There have been attempts at frame-oriented layouts, instead of windows. In your setting, that would mean 3 frames, and the minibuffer/echo area would appear at the bottom of the current one. But it's quite a change to get used to. It would be great if one could get a similar behavior with a single frame divided in windows...

Comment: @Jules Doesn't look like http://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/center-buffer-text-in-emacs deals also with *minibuffers*. Minibuffers are quite a different story.

Comment: Any luck with this one, Dan?

Answer (score 1):

The following advice does this stuff in a hacky way.
One disadvantage I am already aware of is that the spaces are also inserted into the message buffer.

```el
(advice-add #'message :filter-args #'message-filter-center)

(defun message-filter-center (args)
  "Center message string.
This is a :filter-args advice for `message`."
  (if (car args)
      (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window))
    (let ((str (apply #'format-message args)))
      (list "%s" (propertize str 'line-prefix (list 'space :align-to (max 0 (/ (- (window-width (minibuffer-window)) (string-width str)) 2)))))))
    args))
```

EDIT: After the comment of user:blujay I use the `line-prefix` text property instead of the string composed of whitespaces. That text property gets through `message`. Fiddling with the content of the message window directly is quite more involved.

---

I've got the impression that the above version causes some strange problems (e.g., added space at the end of completed lisp-symbols on `C-h f`).
Therefore, I also add the original version here which did not have these problems:

```el
(advice-add #'message :filter-args #'message-filter-center)

(defun message-filter-center (args)
  "Center message string.
This is a :filter-args advice for `message`."
  (if (car args)
      (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window))
    (let* ((str (apply #'format-message args))
           (filler (make-string (max 0 (/ (- (window-width (minibuffer-window)) (string-width str)) 2)) ? )))
      (list "%s%s" filler str)))
    args))
```

Comment: You might be able to use an overlay with the `before-string` property to achieve the same effect without altering the actual contents of the minibuffer: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html#Overlay-Properties

Comment: Thanks, but so far it's not working.  I haven't gotten around to upgrading to emacs 25 yet, so can't tinker with the function (`format-message` is new).